# Invalid broadcasting comparison with block values- Tensorflow

Tags: pandas, tensorflow, python-3.5

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
url = 'http://vincentarelbundock.github.com/Rdatasets/csv/COUNT/medpar.csv'
data=pd.read_csv(url)
X=data[['type2', 'type3','hmo','white']]
y=data[['los']]
size=X.columns.shape
B = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1,size[0]]))
a = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
L=y * a
```

I am getting this error:

```
Invalid broadcasting comparison [<tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable 
object at 0x000000000D7FD7B8>] with block values
```

My end goal is to maximize this function:

```
L=y * tf.log(a)+y*
(tf.matmul(x,B))*tf.log(1+a*tf.exp(tf.matmul(x,B)))+tf.log(tf.gamma(y+1/a))-
tf.log(tf.gamma(1/a))
```

but I am getting this error above in the first term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a day or working on this...

convert y to a matrix.

```
y=data[['los']].as_matrix()
```

Comment: using `.values` on dataframe instead